# Instagram approved app, what happens on features update?

Tags: instagram

As you may know, Instagram has now a permission review process and quite a lack of support for contact forms/emails or other questions beside the API docs.

Here's my scenario:

- an app gets approved through the permission review process and gets access to needed permissions
- in the preview video, the app has certain features free, certain features offered for a price

What happens on several app updates, where the developer can decide to remove some of the options that were locked and make them free? What happens if some options/features are removed and others are added in the app?
There is no word that the permission review process needs to be ran again.  What if I ran the process again and get denied? 
There's no contact email where to write and ask.

Comment: @krisrak I see you answered on many InstagramAPI related questions, any idea on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram has the option to disable app and revoke permissions if there are any violations. Check point C3 in their policy - https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/.